# SignalR JavaScript client API call connection

Tags: asp.net, websocket, asp.net-web-api2, signalr, real-time

As a new to ASP.NET environment and SignalR. I am trying to connect a JavaScript client (WebPage) to an API that includes SignalR HUB (developed using WEB.API 2) using only API Calls.

In other words, I just want to do API call to find my client connected to the signalR hub :

```
/*Instead of doing this*/

var connection = $.hubConnection();
connection.url = "https://www.myAPI.com/signalr/hubs";
var ClientHub = connection.createHubProxy('clientHub');
connection.start()
          .done(...).fail(...);

/*I want to do the following*/

$.post( "https://www.myAPI.com/api/ConnectHUB", someClientData)
 .done(...).fail(...);
```

Is that even possible with simple signalR tools ? or I have to implement something sophisticated myself (With websockets, long pooling and everything I read about) ?

Comment: And why would you want to do this?

Comment: I am developing a customer feedback (Chat) widget that can be integrated on any website, linked to an Agents dashboard via an API. So using only API calls would be a great alternative :)